Call Option Prices not reflecting undelying
Spy went up Friday, Nov 22 [595.51, 0.31%], yet all the OTM (Dec 27) calls, at various strikes (600,605,610) All went down! This makes little sense.
My question is twofold:

How is above possible? Options should not care about the "prospects" or "projections" of price in the future but rather about the absolute value of the underlying. How could all those 3 strikes go down, and not by a small amount too (by 6.46%, 1.13% and .58% respectively on the strikes)

I realize option pricing uses black scholes model which also depends on the volatility and interest rates among a number of other inputs - is there a clear site to calculate SPY option prices in the future assuming a price (as input) to give at least a rough estimate (more accurate preferred of course) of the option price? Say I can forward to next Wed and put in an underlying SPY price of say 605 and it can return to me what the Call strike of 615 Dec 27 would be on Wed (future)? Or can I calculate that somehow manually?




The main reason is that the VIX (implied volatility of the S&P 500) declined 10% on Friday. In addition, all options have a time decay effect that reduces their value every day even with all other parameters equal. Together these counteracted the effect of the increased underlying price.

There are many such sites, e.g., do a search for Black-Scholes option calculator. You can also calculate it manually if you understand all the terms in the formula.



Thanks @nanoman : so you are referring to IV for SPY (this?  https://www.alphaquery.com/stock/SPY/volatility-option-statistics/10-day/iv-mean)  Is that the Rho value in BS model? How does that work intuitively? But typically if VIX goes down, SPY goes UP, so how does that make sense?

Which site has all the interest rates and IVs pre-set to correct values? So I can just plug in the spot price and strike

For example are these values accurate? https://goodcalculators.com/black-scholes-calculator? The option price is way off when I enter spot+strike and Time

I was using the VIX, which is a similar measure, and probably a better fit because it looks at IV over the next 30 (not 10) days, which is roughly the term of your options. IV is sigma (not rho). The derivation of BS assumes that IV remains constant over time and over strikes. The fact that IV does change, and is correlated with the underlying price, calls for a more pragmatic interpretation of BS.

In reality, traders use more sophisticated option pricing models, but whatever price they give, it can be turned into an equivalent BS IV for each option. As to calculating, one approach if you want to estimate pricing with a relatively small change from current parameters (time, IV, underlying) is to use a site that gives you option Greeks and then use those to adjust the current option price for the assumed changes rather than recalculate from scratch.

But just 1 thing i will ask again: IF VIX went down 10% Friday, that is inversely proportional to stock proce going up. Hence VIX is supposed to go down when SPY goes up, so how can that contribute to the options proce going down? Still does not add up.     Also what variable in BS is VIX in?  [time decay minimal 1 day out of 32 days]

@Steve237 "that is inversely proportional to stock proce going up. Hence VIX is supposed to go down when SPY goes up" This assumption is not correct. Volatility can go up and down basically independently from the direction of the underlying (although there can be some bias). And lower volatility means lower option prices (you can test that with the bs calculator), which is what you experienced, isn't it? The value of VIX is in "%", i.e. if VIX is at 16, you use "16%" in your bs calculator as the value for volatility (sigma).

Thanks @Solarflare : So here's one:  If VIX goes UP, does it help Calls or Puts?

@Steve237 If by "help" you mean "increases the price of the option": if VIX goes up, it helps both Calls and Puts.

Sure, but typically (and I emphasize typically), if VIX goes UP, prices go down (on normal basis), hence based on your comment, that's a double-"help" for PUT options in that case.  Hence PUTS come out ahead.

After all these replies (which most certainly help!) I still do not have a Site to go in and calculate a BS output for a SPY option stike!!   With all the values pre-populated.   Closest one I found is this https://goodcalculators.com/black-scholes-calculator/  But it does not match real-prices


Options should not care about the "prospects" or "projections" of price in the future but rather about the absolute value of the underlying.

Options care about the distribution of the probabilities of various values. Suppose there's a call option with a strike price of $95 and expiry date of Jan 30. To make things simple, let's treat the market as risk-neutral, and $90, $100, and $110 as being the only possible values of the stock at Jan 30. Let u = [$90, $100, $110] be a vector that represents these price points, o = [$0, $5, $15] be a vector representing the possible values of the option at expiry, and p = [p_90, p_100, p_110] be a vector representing the probabilities that the market assigns to each other those price points. Then the market price of the underlying will be the dot product of u and p, while the market price of the option will the dot product of o and p.
So if on Jan 1, p = [0.4, 0.2, 0.4], underlying will be $100, while the option will be $7. If on Jan 2, p = [0.0, 0.9, 0.1], then underlying will be $101, but the option will be $6. While the expected (mean) value of the stock went up, the anticipated volatility of the stock went down, decreasing the value of the option.
This sort of thing can happen if there is an important release of information, such as an earnings report, or a major lawsuit is settled, etc.

I modified some numbers so they add up properly -- check if this is what you intended.

Almost no websites and brokers compute American option prices and volatilities properly because it's quite complicated.
Most places use approximations like Roll-Geske-Whaley and Barone-Adesi and Whaley, or Bjerksund-Stensland. However, the approximation is quite bad once you have discrete dividend payments.
Even if they use Cox, Ross and Rubinstein (CRR), which is still relatively easy to implement and accurate, or solve the Black Scholes PDE (what BBG does), you still have the problem of timing (data at the exact time of price update), risk free rates, (implied) dividends and IV. Unless you use the exact same method and market data that the pricing engine of your choice uses, their is no way to replicate the listed price.
You also cannot input the VIX value and expect to get a correct option price, especially not for OTM options. The VIX is not the implied vol that is used for option pricing but a relatively complex formula. https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/75990/54838 has lots of details but it's sufficient to understand that VIX is somewhat close to a 30 day ATM implied vol and that OTM options are almost always using a different IV, for reasons explained on https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/76366/54838.
If you want to replicate option prices, https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/78030/54838 shows how to replicate Bloomberg OVME to the decimal. That only works though because you see the inputs into the model. Would you have to find rates, dividends and IV, there would be no way to do that. Doing this for American options is a lot more complex compared to this example though.
Long story short, the large decline in IV resulted in all option prices to decline (all else equal). What happens to the value on general will depend on all inputs. Since the future is unknown, you anyhow know none of the inputs in advance.
Just use an online calculator like https://optionstrat.com/ and you will get results that will reliable gauge the outcome due to changes in inputs, despite not matching actual quoted values.
